# DragnDrop file in DataGridView

Tags: c#, file, datagridview

I have the following `DataGrid` of name `gridOperations`. I have set `AllowDrop` to true, and used the following code:

```
private void gridOperations_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
    {
        var files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
        foreach (var filePath in files)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(filePath);
        }
    }

}

private void gridOperations_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All;
    else
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
}
```

but when I try to drag file into the `DataGrid`, it gives me the 'STOP' cursor. What am I doing wrong?

Is is possible because it's binded to List?

Basically what I need is to get the filename from file dragged into the datagrid and determinate in which cell its dragged into.

Comment: Just to confirm, but you set `AllowDrop` on the `DataGridView`, right? I ask because the parent form can also allow drag and drop.

Comment: I have also faced similar problem and in my case I hadn't set AllowDrop to true.

Comment: @Kristian If you want the community to help you, you should provide more info about your problem.

Comment: I got the same problem and AllowDrop on datagridview is true, But my datagridview binding source is linked to a dataset table. This whould make some problems, like clear rows error and ...

Answer (score 1):

Are your grid and all the parent controls enabled?

Your code is correct and it works. The only thing I can think of is that your GridView may not be enabled. Can you change the current row of the grid by clicking when the application is running?